# Calculating difference in seconds between two dates not working above a day

Tags: python, datetime

I have a function that accepts a date and returns the difference in time between then and the current time (in seconds). It works fine for everything less than a day. But when I even enter a date that's a year in the future, it still returns a number around 84,000 seconds (there are around 86,400 seconds in a day).

```
def calc_time(date):
    future_date = str(date)
    t_now = str(datetime.utcnow())
    t1 = datetime.strptime(t_now, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    t2 = datetime.strptime(future_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    return ((t2-t1).seconds)
```

Even when I run it with a parameter whose date is in 2014, i get a number way too low.

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Can you include the example parameters that produce the wrong result?

Comment: Sure thing. example paramete = datetime(2013, 6, 3, 8, 38, 30, 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh. apparently .seconds will only return the difference of seconds within the range of a day.

.seconds will include both hours and minutes, so i needed to add that to .days*86400 to get total seconds.

thanks for the help, everyone!  ;D

Answer (score 5):

Reading the [datetime.timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) docs.

> All arguments are optional and default to 0. Arguments may be ints,
>   longs, or floats, and may be positive or negative.
>
> Only days, seconds and microseconds are stored internally. Arguments
>   are converted to those units:
>
> A millisecond is converted to 1000 microseconds. A minute is converted
>   to 60 seconds. An hour is converted to 3600 seconds. A week is
>   converted to 7 days. and days, seconds and microseconds are then
>   normalized so that the representation is unique, with
>
> 0 <= microseconds < 1000000 0 <= seconds < 3600*24 (the number of
>   seconds in one day)
>   -999999999 <= days <= 999999999

The solution is to use `.total_seconds()` instead of `.seconds`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return you the number of days between the two given dates

```
$daysremaining = ceil(abs(strtotime($yourdate) - strtotime($currentdate)) / 86400);
```

and to get the difference in seconds use

```
$secondsremaining = strtotime($yourdate) - strtotime($currentdate);
```

upvote if useful